# Manning the LMG in Operation Swordbreaker

Tags: battlefield-3

In *Battlefield 3*, during Operation Swordbreaker, there is a point where you are told to "Get up on the wall and man the LMG".

I can get up there and man it and then prone, but I keep getting killed shortly after that. Anyone have a good strategy for getting past this point?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The easiest way to pass this point is to grab the LMG and then find cover, you don't actually have to kill anyone. It's all time based (or if it isn't, your squad makes short work of the small amount of people you need to kill), and then a helicopter will fly in and take out the rest.

Comment: Voting this answer down - ok, so it might work, but it seems kinda against the flow of what the game should be :(

Comment: @Spedge I'd agree with you, but try playing it on hard and doing this particular part. I died at least 20 times or so trying to do it right, and dying resets you back about 2-3 minutes, so that's like an hour spent on this one checkpoint.

Comment: Hmm, dang. So that seems like the game is kinda broken then. Boo!

Comment: I found this strategy worked well on hard. You want to spend as little time as possible up on the walkway. Once I had the LMG I took cover back on the top of the steps and shot who I could from there.

Comment: You don't even have to grab the LMG to pass it. You can even sit in cover on the overpass with sniper rifle and you'll still pass that part.

Answer (score 3):

I was stuck on this for a while, too.

The obvious strategy does not include you getting out of that position alive on *hard difficulty*, so you need to pull back.

If you stay on the bridge, you are either gonna get shot, or blown up by the next rpg impact, which was my demise 80% of the time, as I lay prone, hoping I would not be seen immediately.

As soon as you grab the LMG, go to the stairs to the left where you climbed up the overpass and position yourself so, that you cover the pillars while looking at 2 o'clock facing the enemy. You should have no problem suppressing the enemy forces which get too close. You also get a lot of help from your squadron.

Apart from that, I got occasionally a nade lobbed over in my direction, which was easy to evade.

Answer (score 1):

I hung back for a short period after you come out of the basement and I tried to snipe with the alternate weapon. None of my bullets were hitting anybody I was aiming center mass at. I tried aiming higher - nothing. So from what I gather you can't kill the guys until you get up on the bridge. If you then try to kill them from up there you will die, so you must need to go back down the stairs from the bridge quickly, after acquiring the "LMG".

Answer (score 1):

On HARD mode, this is extremely difficult.  Once you get the LMG, look to your 2 O'clock and you'll see continually spawning enemy on the large patio area (some call it a perch) that is eye-level with the bridge you're on. Back up so the guys on the ground can't shoot you. If you keep shooting the guys on that patio to your right, you will eventually get instructions to go down off the bridge and join your squad.  It is important to AIM and not just spray. 2 or 3 round bursts aimed through the 3.4 power scope and you can kill the enemy. That is what I did after dying more times on the bridge than I care to admit.  (OK, it took me almost 2 hours--I'm a retard).  At least one of the RPG rounds comes from that patio area: I saw it shoot from one of the guys just before it hit the bridge.

You may acquire the LMG with much of the concealment wall (the stuff that looks like corrugated aluminum) remaining.  That's good. That gives you about 3 or 4 seconds to creep backwards then deploy your bipod. If your bipod doesn't deploy, reset your aim (right mouse for PC users) and make sure it pops down. If it doesn't, your rounds will fly all over the place. Just keep focused on killing the guys in that patio--they continually pop up from the right. And FOCUS, AIM, short bursts so you don't run out of ammo. It can be done, but then the next challenge is not getting killed when you join your squad.  Stay close to cars, move cover to cover, and watch where your friendlies are shooting so you can shoot the same direction.  Just don't stay out in the open.

Answer (score 0):

I did the same thing as some guy above me said,

1. Run up there after the two guys from your squad have cleared the bridge out
2. Grab the LMG
3. Jump off and go to the stairs to the left. Lay prone there and suppress from that cover.